# Can I open Synaptic Package Manager in a Ubuntu Live CD session?

Tags: installation, live-cd, testdisk

thats the question.

i screwed my harddrive and need to repair it in ubuntu live cd session with test disk that I Have to install with synaptic Package Manager, and I don-t know how to open in this live CD session.

I cant even enter operative system without the cd. I wanted to copy data first before formatting everything. tell me something!! I really need HELP!! thank you

Answer (score 3):

Synaptic package manager isn't  included in the Live CD. but you can install it. But, I think, you should better use the terminal. Open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut and run this command to install testdisk

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

or using the install button below:

[image: Install via the software center]

You can then use testdisk. If you want to install synaptic, use this command instead

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

After installation, use `sudo testdisk` command in the terminal to start using it.

Comment: hey thanks a lot for the answer!I think it installed but I cant seem to find it nowehere, can I open it throught the terminal?

Comment: @GoncaloGaspar yes. testdisk run in the terminal

Comment: Im at it..thanks a lot!! you really helped, hug!

Comment: @GoncaloGaspar glad to know. If it helped you can accept the answer. It will help future visitor. You have to register to the site to accept the answer though.